# std::logic_error::logic_error undefined

Tags: c++, firebase, admob

recently I switched from an older version of firebase to the most recent version.
After the switch, I can't compile my application (even without using firebase code) due to error

```
third_party/java/android/android_ndk_linux/r14/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:127: error: undefined reference to 'std::logic_error::logic_error(char const*)'
  clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

This error goes away as soon as I don't include `#include "firebase/admob.h"`.

I have properly linked against firebase.
I made sure to use `-std=c++11`

Perhaps I'm making a rookie mistake, but I cannot figure this out for the life of me.

I'm happy to provide more information as needed.

Comment: How about a minimal example, as usual for every "why does my code not work" question?

Comment: Compiling with `g++` and not `gcc` (the error relates to missed `-lstdc++`)?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the minimal example is including the admob header file, as I said in my post.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, but the term "minimal example" (or MCVE) is actually from the site rules. I wanted to give you a hint that your question is in violation of those rules simply because you don't provide an MCVE.

Comment: It's fine. Admob's C++ example program mentions not to use Gradle as it doesn't yet work. Switching to ndk-build solved the problem. Wish they would've mentioned that in their online documentation, but whatever.

Comment: I have the same problem using Qt framework. I'm start thinking there is some kind of issue with the latest firebase version.

Comment: I don't think there is. I'm using the latest version and it works fine. Are you able to download the [firebase cpp quickstart admob example](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-cpp/tree/master/admob/testapp) and run the admob example? That's how I found out it was me and not my version.

Comment: Ok, I just realice I should use LIBS += -L$${FIREBASE_SDK}/libs/android/armeabi-v7a/gnustl instead of LIBS += -L$${FIREBASE_SDK}/libs/android/armeabi-v7a/c++ using the latest firebase version (4.4.2)

Answer (score 5):

Judging from undefined reference to `std::logic_error::logic_error` linker message it looks like you are linking with `gcc`. You need to link `C++` applications with `g++`. Or link with `gcc` and add `-lstdc++` to the linker command line.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that didn't work. I put it in my cppFlags, and the errors are still there. Can see -lstd++ when the project is compiling

Comment: Can you please demonstrate what you see without any cut offs? -lstdc++ is not useful when the project is compiling. This flag is for linking.

Comment: Yep, `--sysroot=C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/ndk-bundle/sysroot -fPIC -isystem C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/x86_64-linux-android -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -std=c++11 -D_IRR_ANDROID_PLATFORM_ -DLUA_ANSI -DLUA_USE_APICHECK -lstdc++ -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a`
Thanks for your help

Comment: Thank you. I do not know what is wrong there. I would try to disable exceptions with the flag `-fno-exceptions`. I do not have thoughts more.